# Java While loop never ends

Tags: java, while-loop

I have problem with A while loop. Looks like it never ends and tryLadowanie() never runs. I guess something is wrong with this: while( (xPosition != xTarget) && (yPosition != yTarget) ). Update() works just fine, it goes from point A to point B just fine, but once it is in point B it still runs.  What do you think ?

Here is my code:

```
public void lecimy(Lotnisko source, Lotnisko dest){
    xPosition = source.coords.getX();
    yPosition = source.coords.getY();
    xTarget = dest.coords.getX();
    yTarget = dest.coords.getY();

    while( (xPosition != xTarget) && (yPosition != yTarget) ) {
        update();

        try {
            sleep(100);// ok 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    tryLadowanie();
}

public void update() {
    paliwo -= 0.05;
    double dx = xTarget - xPosition;
    double dy = yTarget - yPosition;
    double length = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

    dx /= length;
    dy /= length;

    if (Math.abs(dest.coords.getX() - source.coords.getX()) < 1)
        dx = 0;
    if (Math.abs(dest.coords.getY() - source.coords.getY()) < 1)
        dy = 0;
        xPosition += dx;
        yPosition += dy;
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you declare xPosition and yPosition? are declared somewhere outside the two functions? static?

Comment: print and debug the value of `xPosition != xTarget) && (yPosition != yTarget`. It is the problem with your condition in `while` loop.

Comment: Try checking if it's *close* to the `target`, rather than exactly the same. `double` types can be extremely long, and will be considered unequal even if they are `0.00001` off.

Comment: xPosition and yPosition are double, declared outside the two functions, not static just double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a logical error:

You say: "if destination.X is closer than '1' from source.X then don't move it any closer (dx = 0)."

This can potentially go on forever.

To answer your comment-question (lack of space and editing in comment section):

Move the `if (Math.abs(dest.coords.getX() - source.coords.getX()) < 1)` and `if (Math.abs(dest.coords.getY() - source.coords.getY()) < 1)` out into the while loop's condition.

You don't want to stop changing the position when it's getting close inside the update() method, instead you want your loop to stop. Otherwise the loop will keep running and the update() method will do nothing.

Comment: Like this: while( (Math.abs(dest.coords.getX() - source.coords.getX()) < 1) && (Math.abs(dest.coords.getY() - source.coords.getY()) < 1) )

Comment: Move it like this ? Or.. ?

Answer (score 3):

Comparing `double`-variables using `==` or `!=` is bound to get you in trouble, since the tiniest rounding-error will break your comparison. Use something like `Math.abs(xPosition - xTarget) < tolerance`.